# Creating a 8x8 table using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hey there new to Angular and trying to build a 8x8 table evenly distributed across the page.
eg.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Except of course in the form {{i+j}} for each td entry as shown in the code.
At the moment it looks like:

```
0123 4 5 6 7
0123 4 5 6 7
0123 4 5 6 7
0123 4 5 6 7
0123 4 5 6 7
0123 4 5 6 7
0123 4 5 6 7
0123 4 5 6 7
```

Not sure why but my table is not evenly distributed, here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">

  <table>
    <tr><th colspan = '8'>row number</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">
      <td ng-repeat="j in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">{{i+j}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Only css that could impact it is the bootstrap since I have nothing in my app.css file. Thank you!

Comment: tr is inside th, not the other way round. th stands for table head, there's also a tbody, for table body. Each have their own rows.

Comment: th must be inside tr !

Comment: Ok I have reformatted the question for you

Comment: I know the problem isn't clear that's why I'm asking its just randomly formatting like that? There is nothing in my css file and all the angular is there so why isn't there a single space between each td as we could expect?

Comment: Do you see the problem in this fiddle? If not, modify it so the problem *does* appear, update it, and post the URL in your question. http://jsfiddle.net/ta3n5sxd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<tr><th colspan="8">row number</th></tr>
------------^
```

---

After re-reading, I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] track by $index">
  <th>row number {{%index}}</th>
  <td ng-repeat="j in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">{{i+j}}</td>
</tr>
```

---

Ok, maybe this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">
  <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
  <td ng-repeat="j in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">{{j}}</td>
</tr>
```

### **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ta3n5sxd/1)**

If all you're asking about is CSS, try this one:

```
th, td {
  width: 12.5%;
}
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ta3n5sxd/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

You problem is not coming from AngularJS but the HTML !

You defined a row above the ng-repeats with only one column `row number`

That's why you are getting this problem!

Comment: So I should do something like <tr><th colspan = '8'>row number</th></tr>?

Comment: do a colspan 8 since you have 8 columns below :)

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is not fixed see my comment to the answer below

Comment: That's a pure CSS problem there ! It's still not related to how Angular generates the table with ng-repeat. Put `table-layout:fixed;` on your table and put a width and a height to one of the `<td>` and you'll get the result you wanted ! Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/hyukchan/U3pVM/23253/ Don't forget the green tick so people understands the problem has been fixed !

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are setting the first column's width to 100% using `<col width="100%"></col>`. What you wanted to achieve was presumably having the table header span the full table. To accomplish this, you should use the `colspan` attribute.

```
<table>
   <tr><th colspan="8">row number</th></tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">
      <td ng-repeat="j in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">{{i+j}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit:** To have equally spaced columns, you want to add the `table-layout: fixed` CSS rule to the table, and give the table a width. Something like this:

```
<style>
   #myTable {
      table-layout: fixed;
      width: 100%;
   }
</style>

<table id="myTable">
   <tr><th colspan="8">row number</th></tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">
      <td ng-repeat="j in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">{{i+j}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Add additional CSS as necessary to achieve the look you desire with regards to borders, text centering etc.

Comment: works better except the first columns are bunched together and the last columns have spaces between them? I would like a nice square table..

Comment: I've added the CSS to get equal cell spacing. As your original problem has been resolved I'll leave it at that.